# Как изолировать вызовы и заставить их друг с другом дружить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

На странице есть огромное количество каруселей (они симовлизируют покупки), каждый элемент карусели кликабельный и вызывает раздвигающийся блок с информацией под этой каруселью (этот блок я сделал один, информация в него подгружаться будет с помощью AJAX, почему он один? - потому что вынесен в обертку из карусели, т.к. у нее высота фиксированная из-за анимации при наведении, а мне необходимо, чтобы раздвигающийся блок толкал все остальные).

Изолировать карусели по отдельности у меня получилось, здесь ничего сложного не было.

1. Теперь необходимо внутри самой карусели просто между элементами переносить класс активности, я знаю, что решение простое, но сам дойти до него не могу.
2. Внутри самого раздвигающегося блока появилась

Мой js для этого:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var active = 'carousel-flights-item--active';


    //element-carousel
    $('.js-flights-info-trigger').click(function(){

            if ($(this).hasClass(active)) {

                $(this).removeClass(active);
                $(this).parents().children('.js-flights-info-slide').slideToggle();

            } else {

                $(this).addClass(active);
                $(this).parents().children('.js-flights-info-slide').slideToggle();

            }

        }
    );


    //inside
    $('.js-flights-info-trigger-slide-up').click(function(){

            if ($(this).parents().children('.carousel-flights-item').hasClass(active)) {

                $(this).parents().children('.carousel-flights-item').removeClass(active);
                $(this).parents().children('.js-flights-info-slide').slideToggle();

            } else {

                $(this).parents().children('.carousel-flights-item').addClass(active);
                $(this).parents().children('.js-flights-info-slide').slideToggle();

            }

        }
    );

});
```

Жду помощи, заранее спасибо! Если решение не элегантное, предлагайте другое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var active = 'carousel-flights-item--active';

    var $triggerItems = $('.js-flights-info-trigger');
    var $infoSlideItems = $('.js-flights-info-slide');

    //element-carousel
    $triggerItems.click(function(){
        var isActive = $(this).hasClass(active);
        $triggerItems.removeClass(active);  
        $infoSlideItems.slideUp();

        if (!isActive) {
          $(this).addClass(active)
            .parents().children('.js-flights-info-slide')
            .stop(true, false)
            .slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Надеюсь я Вашу задачу правильно понял.
Менял в js только блок `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Я думаю сегодня оформлю это все на jsfiddle, как до компьютера доберусь.

Comment: Выложил на codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpjbBK

Comment: Исправил свой ответ.